# Microsoft Edge does not fire UIA HandlePropertyChangedEvent when window title property changes

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to get notified when the Window title of an MS Edge browser window changes using UIAutomation but the property changed event is not firing as I would expect.

The code works for IE, Chrome and FireFox and the only noticeable difference I can see when inspecting the window using Accessibility Insights is that they implement the IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern interface and MS Edge does not but as I can see the property changing I would still expect the event to fire.

Before I go looking for a work around e.g. using SetWindowHook to trigger the title change event I'm wondering if there is a small change I can make to get MS Edge working?

Here is a how I'm creating the handler

```
     IUIAutomationElement rootElement = _uIA.GetRootElement();

     IUIAutomationCacheRequest cacheRequest = _uIA.CreateCacheRequest();
     cacheRequest.AddProperty(UIA_NamePropertyId);

     IUIAutomationCondition windowCondition = _uIA.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NativeWindowHandlePropertyId, handle);
     IUIAutomationElement windowElement = rootElement.FindFirstBuildCache(TreeScope.TreeScope_Descendants, windowCondition, cacheRequest);
     if (windowElement == null)
          return false;                                                                          
                                                                                                 
     int[] props = { UIA_NamePropertyId };

     _uIA.AddPropertyChangedEventHandler(windowElement, TreeScope.TreeScope_Element, cacheRequest, this, props);
```

The code works fine for getting the window and I can see the title chaging on the windowElement.CacheName it just never fires the HandlePropertyChangedEvent.

To clarify I'm using a wrapper around uiautomationclient and not the .net automation framework